# awk bash command takes error when I use it in tcl

Tags: tcl

when I run command

`awk '/^proc/ {print $2}' <file_name>`

in bash I have no problem. But when I use it in `Tcl` script using `exec` function   as

`exec awk "/^proc/ {print $2}" win_test.tcl` ,

I recevie `error can't read "2": no such variable`

Comment: Tcl will interpolate variables in a double quoted string. The Tcl equivalent of single quotes is `{braces}`

Answer (score 3):

Enclose the `awk` command without single quotes and then use `exec`.

```
set awkCmd {/^proc/ {print $2}}
exec awk $awkCmd <file-name>
```

**Example**

```
[dinesh@mypc mypgms]$ cat sample.tcl
proc Hello {} {
}

proc World {} {
}

[dinesh@mypc mypgms]$ tclsh
% set awkCmd {/^proc/ {print $2}}
/^proc/ {print $2}
% exec awk $awkCmd sample.tcl
Hello
World
%
```

Comment: The use of braces is vital. The use of a separate variable is not.